# I keep getting the same number for number of minutes premium service was used and amount due

Tags: c++

I keep getting a fixed number for Number of minutes premium service was used and for amount due. I have tried putting parentheses, and it still gives me a fixed number. Also  I have tried to change the addition signs for multiplication and still I get a fixed number. If there is anything else wrong with my code please point it out I'd appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Account_Number;
    char Service_Code;
    float Regular_Service_Standard_Fee = 10.00;
    float Regular_Service_Additional_Fee = 0.20;
    float Premium_Service_Stanard_Fee = 25.00;
    float Premium_Service_Day_Fee = 0.10;
    float Premium_Service_Night_Fee = 0.05;
    int Regular_Service_Minutes;
    int Premium_Service_Day_Minutes;
    int Premium_Service_Night_Minutes;
    int Total_Premium_Service_Minutes;
    float Amount_Due = 0;

    cout << "Enter account number. \n";
    cin >> Account_Number;
    cout << "Enter service code. \n";
    cin >> Service_Code;
    cout << "Enter number of minutes the service was used. \n";
    cin >> Minutes;

    if (Service_Code == 'R' || Service_Code == 'r') {
        cout << "Regular service selected. \n";
        cout << "Enter number of minutes used. \n";
        cin >> Regular_Service_Minutes;
    }
    else if (Service_Code == 'P' || Service_Code == 'p') {
        cout << "Premium service selected. \n";
        cout << "Enter the number of minutes used during the day. \n";
        cin >> Premium_Service_Day_Minutes;
        cout << "Enter the number of minutes used during the day. \n";
        cin > Premium_Service_Night_Minutes;
        Total_Premium_Service_Minutes = Premium_Service_Day_Minutes + Premium_Service_Night_Minutes;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error! Select R or P! \n";

    if (Regular_Service_Minutes > 50)
        Amount_Due = Regular_Service_Minutes - 50 * Regular_Service_Additional_Fee + Regular_Service_Standard_Fee;
    else
        Amount_Due = Regular_Service_Standard_Fee;

    if (Premium_Service_Day_Minutes > 75)
        Amount_Due = (Premium_Service_Day_Minutes - 75) + Premium_Service_Day_Fee;

    else if (Premium_Service_Night_Minutes > 100)
        Amount_Due = (Premium_Service_Night_Minutes - 100) + Premium_Service_Night_Fee;

    else
        Amount_Due = Amount_Due + Premium_Service_Stanard_Fee;

    cout << "Account # : " << Account_Number << endl;
    cout << "Type of service : " << Service_Code << endl;
    cout << "Number of minutes regular telephone service was used : "
         << Regular_Service_Minutes << endl;
    cout << "Number of minutes premium telephone service was used : "
         << Total_Premium_Service_Minutes << endl;
    cout << "Amount Due : " << Amount_Due << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and, more important, read this: [ask]

Comment: This code doesn't compile. What is `Minutes`?

Comment: Also a typo at `cin>Premium_Service_Night_Minutes;`

Comment: Initialise your variables.

Comment: Agreed, I just noticed that at the end you print `Regular_Service_Minutes` but if service is 'P', that variable never gets set. And the opposite is true if service is 'R'.

Comment: If I wanted to just use one line and print number of minutes telephone service was used. How would I be able to do that? Also initialize my regular and premium minutes variables to 0? Is there anything else wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow (SO).

A few pointers:

- Try to make your code readable. Refactor! Refactoring will not only show you where your code lacks the attention, but it will expose logical errors too.
- Always initialise your variables when they live inside a scope. C++ will initialise your variables only when it comes for free.

@local scope:

```
void foo()
{
    int num; //num is undefined - i.e. garbage value
}
```

@ global scope

```
int num; //num is 0.
```

- floats should ideally be followed by a .f to avoid converting from a double. ex: `float b = 10.0f;`
- Create a simplified version of your program and run it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang) to make sure that it works, before posting on SO.

I've tried to quickly simplify your code below and it seems to work for me. I'm not sure about the logic of your program though. You may want to revisit a few sections.

The code can be found [here](http://rextester.com/GPE3300). (click on *show input* and enter the values for the cin before you run the code on rextester)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Also, I recently started learning C++ so my professor hasn't taught advanced programming in my class yet so I kinda don't understand the code you wrote lol but either way I appreciate it very much! I also seem to be having problems with my calculations in my programs. Do you have any advice on how to fix that and improve? Thank you once again!

Comment: @David : I see... In that case, your best friends are print outs. Comment out everything in your code, and I mean absolutely everything inside your main function. Uncomment the first line of code and put a print right after it. ex: int Account_Number; std::cout<< Account_Number <<std::endl; . What **should** Account_Number be at that stage? Should it be 0? If so, you're in for a surprise. Initialise it. Then move on to the next line until the end of the program. Try to find the answers for each print before running the program. If you have a std::cin, guess what the user might enter.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help!